# Proximity based actions based on Wi-Fi signal

Tags: ios, wifi, ibeacon, beacon

Does iOS support proximity based actions when detecting a specific Wi-Fi signal?

E.g. similarly to what happens with [iBeacons](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/) is it possible to detect entering a Wi-Fi region?

I have found this article on Wi-Fi Aware which is interesting: 
http://www.wi-fi.org/beacon/rolf-de-vegt/wi-fi-aware-a-platform-for-proximity-based-wi-fi-innovation

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately, iOS does not provide third party apps access to visible WiFi networks.**

There are private APIs that some apps use to detect the name of the currently connected WiFi network, but that is of limited use because a user will not connect to every WiFi network when moving around.  The CoreLocation component of the operating system itself does use visible WiFi networks to help infer it's latitude and longitude, but the mechanism is internal, closed source and not exposed to the user.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. There was a change in this private API's last year (for some time you could get the Wi-Fi SSID, then they deprecated it and now seems to be available again). I was wondering if there are rumours of Apple activating some feature/API similar to the iBeacon "didEnterRegion" for Wi-Fi's. It would be immensely handy.